# Reinstantiate a component in angular 4

Tags: angular, components

I am using a component to display canvas image in it. For the first time it works fine. After displaying I hide it but after I display the component again it shows me the previous image but I already change the image source.

So I want to ask is there any way I can destroy this instance of component so that when it is again rendered it re-initializes everything?

I want to re-initialize it because there are many other member variables in the component I want them to re-initialize too.

Notice : already tried ngonchange

Comment: if you hide it with *ngIf it shold regenerate itself each time it shown

Comment: i have a close button to hide it. But its just hiding its not regenerating when displayed again

Comment: It worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

With a little hack of the `*ngFor` template you can create a new instance on change :

Template :

```
<ng-template #MyTemplate let-name="name">
  <hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
</ng-template>

<ng-container *ngFor="let value of values">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="MyTemplate;context:{name: value}">
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>

<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" (ngModelChange)="change($event)">
```

Component :

```
  values = ['Template'];


  change(event) {
    this.values.pop();
    this.values.push(event);
  }
```

[You can find a running example here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-49276542) The count displays the instances count.

Comment: I'm actually trying to figure out why there isn't a "clean" way to do this in angular, but you saved me from writing a ton of code to update a component that did not take an observable as an input

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by creating a dynamic component...

You have to follow this steps to do this:

in your parent html:

```
<ng-template #dynamic></ng-template>
```

in your parent component.ts file:

```
@ViewChild("dynamic", {read: ViewContainerRef}) container;
componentRef: ComponentRef<any>;

constructor(...
              private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
...) 

    createComponent() {
      if (this.componentRef) this.componentRef.destroy();
      this.container.clear();
      const factoryGleam: ComponentFactory<YourComponent> = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(YourComponent);
      this.componentRef = this.container.createComponent(factoryGleam);
}

ngOnDestroy() {
if (this.componentRef) this.componentRef.destroy();
}
```

Use your createComponent() method when you want to create a component again...

And in your parent module:

```
  ...
  providers: ...,
  entryComponents: [YourComponent]
```

Or you could read this article:
https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/dynamically-add-components-to-the-dom-with-angular-71b0cb535286

Comment: I donot want to destroy it completely. I want the component but I just want to re-initialize everything in that component when I display it again.

Answer (score 0):

> So I want to ask is there any way I can destroy this instance of
>   component so that when it is again rendered it re-initializes
>   everything?

**[Code example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-component-reinit?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

In your parent component template:

```
  <child-comp *ngIf="isShown">
  </child-comp>
   <button (click)="toggleChild()">Toggle</button>
   <button (click)="reInit()">ReInitialize</button>
```

**Parent Component class:**

```
class ParentComponent{

    isShown = false;

    toggleChild(){       
       this.isShown = !this.isShown;
    }


    reInit() {
       this.isShown = false;
        setTimeout(() =>{
           this.isShown = true;
        });
    }
}
```

**setTimeout** is needed if we want re-initialize component immediately. Without it component will not re-initialized in one digest cycle. In first cycle component is destroyed, **setTimeout** forces to init component in next cycle.